# how to save values of settings only on install of the app in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to determine know how and where to save the settings of an app I am building on install only rather than every time the app is opened so that it doesn't reset the options. I'm not sure if there is any code that needs to be shared, but I will share the SettingsScreen.js

I checked some of the videos on YouTube, but what I found only talks about the login and keeping a user logged in.

How can I save settings on install only using React Native?

```
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    LayoutAnimation,
} from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import colors from '../config/colors';

export default function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
    const [isNotificationOn, setIsNotificationOn] = useState(true);

    const onColor = 'green';
    const offColor = colors.primary;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.textView}>
                <Text style={styles.notificationText}>Notifications: </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.buttonView}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={[
                        styles.touchable,
                        { borderColor: isNotificationOn ? onColor : offColor },
                    ]}
                    onPress={() => {
                        LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
                        setIsNotificationOn(!isNotificationOn);
                    }}
                >
                    <View
                        style={[
                            styles.innerView,
                            {
                                backgroundColor: isNotificationOn
                                    ? onColor
                                    : offColor,
                                alignSelf: isNotificationOn
                                    ? 'flex-end'
                                    : 'flex-start',
                            },
                        ]}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                            {isNotificationOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 15,
        paddingBottom: 50,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: colors.white,
    },
    textView: {
        width: '70%',
    },
    buttonView: {
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: '500',
    },
    innerView: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '50%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    notificationText: {
        color: colors.darkGray,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'Roboto' : 'Avenir',
        width: '50%',
    },
    touchable: {
        height: 40,
        width: 80,
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        overFlow: 'hidden',
    },
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

I did these steps but seems the app is not saving the value after i close the app, it is just being saved only when i navigate away from the screen

here is my code:

`

```
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    LayoutAnimation,
} from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import colors from '../config/colors';

export default function SettingsScreen() {
    const [isNotificationOn, setIsNotificationOn] = useState();

    const onColor = 'green';
    const offColor = colors.primary;

    const retrieveSettings = async () => {
        console.log('retrieving');
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('notificationOn');
            console.log('value: ', JSON.parse(value));
            if (value !== null) {
                // We have data!!
                setIsNotificationOn(JSON.parse(value));
            } else {
                console.log('it is null');
                setIsNotificationOn(true);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // Error retrieving data
        }
    };

    const saveSettings = async (value) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('notificationOn', JSON.stringify(value));
            console.log('saved: ', value);
        } catch (error) {
            // Error retrieving data
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveSettings();
        console.log('on: ', isNotificationOn);
    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.textView}>
                <Text style={styles.notificationText}>Notifications: </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.buttonView}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={[
                        styles.touchable,
                        { borderColor: isNotificationOn ? onColor : offColor },
                    ]}
                    onPress={() => {
                        LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
                        setIsNotificationOn(!isNotificationOn);
                        saveSettings(isNotificationOn);
                    }}
                >
                    <View
                        style={[
                            styles.innerView,
                            {
                                backgroundColor: isNotificationOn
                                    ? onColor
                                    : offColor,
                                alignSelf: isNotificationOn
                                    ? 'flex-end'
                                    : 'flex-start',
                            },
                        ]}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                            {isNotificationOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 15,
        paddingBottom: 50,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: colors.white,
    },
    textView: {
        width: '70%',
    },
    buttonView: {
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: '500',
    },
    innerView: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '50%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    notificationText: {
        color: colors.darkGray,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'Roboto' : 'Avenir',
        width: '50%',
    },
    touchable: {
        height: 40,
        width: 80,
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        overFlow: 'hidden',
    },
});
```

`

Answer (score -1):

You can use Async storage in react native. It works like local storage and might be the solution you are looking for. Hope its helps .link to doc:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage

Comment: thanks for your comment, so how can i use it only on install and then if the value changes in settings then save it ?

Comment: i did it, it worked only if the app is open, when i close the app everything goes back to the original state, so how can i make it save even if the app is off ?

Comment: Async Storage is deprecated in the official versions. Please use the community supported one: `npm install --save @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`. https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/

Comment: @cela thank you i will modify and add my response

Comment: @cela I edited my update but the values are not being saved so how can i do it ?

Comment: Async storage is the only way I could think of , for achieving what you are trying to do. even if app is off . Async storage will work fine. But if you are uninstalling and reinstalling the app again . then I am afraid , it won't work. For this you have to save the settings or data in backend or any other database storage option. if any other questions feel free to ask